# Excel Time Function to VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I have this number - 2411 [put in cell A2], which is the number of seconds since the start of an activity. Now I know the start time of the activity which is 07/30/2016 13:11:18. In excel if I want to convert this seconds to time, I can use this formula - Time(13,11,(18+A2)), which will return - 1:15 PM. I have close to 1500 lines of such numbers, and I know I can apply this formula and drag it till the end to get the details. In VBA do we have a code which can do the same function?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `TimeSerial(13,11,18 + Range("A2").Value)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Record Macro button for Excel to generate the VBA code based on your actions.

The shorter version can be something like

```
Sub a()
    Range("B2:B1500").Formula = "=Time(13,11,(18+A2))"
End Sub
```